# String path validation

Tags: c#, path

I have here a string(an input from the user) for a file path. I checked the string so that it will qualify the criteria:

- ***check for invalid characters for a file path***
- ***will not accept absolute path*** *(\Sample\text.txt)*

Invalid characters are:

< > : " / \ | ? *

I have tried catching these invalid characters in catch clause. It work except for '\'. It will accept 'C:\\Sample\text.txt' which is an invalid file path.

**The following examples should be invalid paths:**

- :\text.txt
- :text.txt
- \:text.txt
- \text.txt
- C:\\\text.txt

**The ff. is an example of a valid path:**

- C:\text.txt

I have been through similar questions posted here but none of them seemed to solve my issue.

What would be the best way to do such check?

Comment: What should be a valid path ?

Comment: You want to say that if a path having "\" or "/" would be invalid?

Comment: I have editted my question, putting a list of invalid chars..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use [Path.GetFullPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfullpath.aspx), it will throw an exception if the path is invalid. You can have method like:

```
public static bool IsValidPath(string path)
{
    try
    {
       path = path.Replace(@"\\", ":"); // to cancel out c:\\\\test.text
       string temp = Path.GetPathRoot(path); //For cases like: \text.txt
       if (temp.StartsWith(@"\"))
            return false;
       string pt = Path.GetFullPath(path);
    }
    catch //(Exception NotSupportedException) // catch specific exception here or not if you want
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Sample code to test:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>()
{
    @":\text.txt",
    @":text.txt",
    @"\:text.txt",
    @"\text.txt",
    @"C:\\\text.txt",
    @"C:\text.txt",

};

foreach(string str in list)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Path: {0} is Valid = {1}" ,str,IsValidPath(str));
}
```

Output:

```
Path: :\text.txt is Valid = False
Path: :text.txt is Valid = False
Path: \:text.txt is Valid = False
Path: \text.txt is Valid = False
Path: C:\\\text.txt is Valid = False
Path: C:\text.txt is Valid = True
```

Comment: This solution says valid on C:\\Sample\text.txt and C:\\\text.txt. However they're valid in Windows.

Comment: @AndreyStukalin, Path.GetFullPath, ignores the `(\\)` and consider it once, you may replace it with some invalid character like `:` and then check. I have updated the answer. Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: When "C:\\\text.txt" is being inputted, and I will get Path.GetFullPath(path), "C:\text.txt" is being returned..

Comment: @CMAñora, did you try the edited version, where I have replaced double backslash with `:` ?

Comment: @Habib it was _now_. Sorry for that

Comment: @Habib:I am giving input as 
@"D:\Main\mysiteResearch\project_name\project.Web\StaticResources\2012\ClientPrint\6319522\NY 1120New York Blank Forms (2).pdf" and it returns false, What could be the reason. When I run this path from run command, it opens correct file.

Answer (score 1):

Use regex.match() method for file path validation as :

```
Match match = Regex.Match(input, ^(?:[\w]\:|\\)(\\[a-z_\-\s0-9\.]+)+\.(?i)(txt|gif|pdf|doc|docx|xls|xlsx)$,
        RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Comment: D:\Main\sitename Research\Project_Mayank\Project.Web\StaticResources\2012\ClientPrint\6319522\NY 1120New York Blank Forms (2).pdf is not working for me. What could be the reason ?