# Check whenever string is valid path

Tags: c#, .net, path, uri

I'm trying to use `Uri.IsWellFormedUriString` but it doesn't work, and question is - why:

```
class Program
{

    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(IsWellFormed(@"C:\Windows"));
        Console.WriteLine(IsWellFormed(@"C:\\:\\//Windows32"));
    }

    public static bool IsWellFormed(string path)
    {
        string uriString = "file:///" + path;
        string wellFormed = uriString.Replace('\\', '/');
        return Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(wellFormed, UriKind.Absolute);
    }
}
```

expected `true false` output but it returns `true` in both cases. And I'm really confused a bit.

Comment: Do you know exactly what doesn't work? Does it return false or does it return an error? The second call of isWellFormed seems a bit odd: C:\:\//Windows32

Comment: Im not convinced this is a fully fledged answer but the remarks in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.iswellformeduristring(v=vs.110).aspx) state it conforms to the standards set by RFC 2396 and RFC 2732, and by looking at the examples, it seems like your strings do that

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use Directory.Exists() or File.Exists() to check the correct path? If you'll have to use it you can try to create it also.. anyway you'll get an error if the path is invalid that you can catch and analyse.

Comment: Of course, there is one solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12947405/string-path-validation
but i'm looking for something better than `try-catch-return false`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach without try/catch, though it may not be optimal:

```
        public static bool IsWellFormed(string path)
        {
            string path = "C:\\windows\\:ppz";
            var isRooted = Path.IsPathRooted(path);
            var root = Path.GetPathRoot(path);
            var list = path.Split(new char[] {Path.DirectorySeparatorChar}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);            
            for (int i = 0; i < list.Length; i ++)
            {
                if(i == 0 && isRooted && s[i]+"\\" == root) continue;
                if (s[i].Intersect(Path.GetInvalidPathChars()).Count() != 0)
                    return false;
                if (s[i].Intersect(Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars()).Count() != 0)
                    return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
```

You can play with your values and see if this fits your task. You can also customize your own lists for invalid chars.